# checkbox to select all values of a listbox

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I would like a checkbox , that when checked, selects all values in a listbox.
To see if the checkbox is checked I use :

`if (getComponent('checkBox1').getValue() == "true") {
// how select all items of for example listbox1
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `setSelectedValues()` method of the listbox component, and pass in an Array containing all of the values of the listbox, e.g. ["value1","value2","value3"]. Put this in the onChange event of the checkbox, with a partial refresh of the listbox, and that should do what you want.

If you don't want to hard code the listbox values in your SSJS, but rather pull the available values from the listbox, check out this [XSnippet by Sven Hasselbach](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=get-selectable-values-of-a-component). Using that snippet, I made an example below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
<xp:checkBox text="Select All" id="checkBox1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="listBox1">
        <xp:this.action>
            <![CDATA[#{javascript:
                //Get the listbox component
                var listbox = getComponent('listBox1');
                if (getComponent('checkBox1').getValue() == "true") {
                    //Checkbox is checked
                    //Get an iterator for the items in the listbox              
                    var childrenList:java.util.ListIterator;
                    childrenList = listbox.getChildren().listIterator();

                    //Generate the array of items
                    var itemList = [];
                    while (childrenList.hasNext()) {
                        var child = childrenList.next();
                        itemList.push(child.getItemValue());
                    }

                    //Set the selectedValues of the listbox
                    listbox.setSelectedValues(itemList);
                }else if(getComponent('checkBox1').getValue() == "false") {
                    //Checkbox is unchecked
                    //Set listbox to have no selections, empty array
                    listbox.setSelectedValues([]);
                }
            }]]>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:checkBox>
<xp:br />
<xp:listBox id="listBox1" multiple="true" style="height:200px;width:150px">
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="value1" itemValue="value1"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="value2" itemValue="value2"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="value3" itemValue="value3"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="value4" itemValue="value4"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="value5" itemValue="value5"></xp:selectItem>
</xp:listBox>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I'm dooing this for the end user. It's faster to check a checkbox to select all items of a listbox than to manually select them (if you have a lot of them)